# Use php variable in sql statement with concatenation

Tags: php, sql, string, variables, concatenation

I have a variable below (storecode) which is getting it's value from the user's input (120)

```
$storecode = $_POST['storecode'];
```

The sql which works otherwise in PL/SQL Developer is `Select mydate from tbl_store@rm_database.p120081`;

I am trying to put the $storecode variable in replacement of the "120" and then concatenate "081" so I have:

```
 " SELECT mydate from tbl_store@rm_database.p'$storecode'" "081";
```

Obviously the above is wrong and wanted some guidance to fix this

Comment: try " SELECT mydate from tbl_store@rm_database.p" . $storecode . "081";

Comment: Why did I get a negative rating for my question???  I even showed the query I was trying to attempt on my own, I looked at other posts and examples but the problem was trying to concatenate withing a SQL statement with a variable, I am still fairly new to PHP and is not something I write in each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable table_name and add your concatenated databasename.tablename to that variable like

```
var table_name = 'tbl_store@rm_database.p'.$storecode.'081'
```

Then in your query you can use this variable as

```
"SELECT mydate from ".$table_name;
```

I m not php developer this is just for idea i m sharing the code based on my basic knowledge of php, so you would require to solve syntactical error.

Answer (score 0):

The single-quotes in your expression are being added to the tablename so, assuming `$storecode = 120`, this statement:

```
 "SELECT mydate from tbl_store@rm_database.p'$storecode'081";
```

... results in a literal tablename of `tbl_store@rm_database.p'120'081`

You can concatenate as suggested in the other answers; however, you can achieve the same result within the string definition with knowledge of [variable parsing](http://php.net/language.types.string) (look for Simple Syntax under Variable Parsing section).

```
 "SELECT mydate from tbl_store@rm_database.p{$storecode}081";
```

> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the name.

Without the braces, the parser would try to reference variable `$storecode081`.

So you were on the right lines originally, you just needed the brace syntax rather than single-quotes.